# What information is given about the age and history of Mori Summer in the Chuunibyo light novels?

Tags: love-chunibyo-and-other-delusions

As a follow-up to [What information is given about the age and history of Mori Summer in the Chuunibyo anime?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/67919/70615), I'm curious- what information is given about the age and history of Mori Summer in the Chuunibo light novels? And what are the qualities of the sources of that information (first-hand / second-hand / possibly faulty memory / citable from writings)?

Note that I'm purposely asking these as two separate question posts because of [How much does the Chuunibyou anime differ from the light novels?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3559/70615).

Comment: meta note: before posting this, I checked meta and found [Can we also discuss visual novels, light novels and other related media?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3/70615), where the answers seem to indicate a question like this about the light novel for an anime is ok. Let me know if that's not the case.